# Why does JSF validation clear valid input on validation?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have the following JSF 2.2 bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import com.tss.model.Revision;
import com.tss.services.RevisionService;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class RevisionBean {

    private Revision revision;

    private RevisionService revisionService;

    public RevisionBean() {
        revision = new Revision();
        revisionService = new RevisionService();
    }

    public Revision getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }

    public void setRevision(Revision revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }

    public void submit() {
        revisionService.submitRevision(revision);
    }

}
```

and the following classes:

```
public class Revision {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class RevisionService {

    public void submitRevision(Revision revision) {
        System.out.println("done=revision");
    }

}
```

If the name field is left invalid (empty) the value of Code is cleared on submission ...

[image: name field is required]

below the result (value 1 lost):

[image: code value was lost ...]

-> I don't need to use ajax and I'm sure that I'm losing some basic detail because this is a very common use case (the user couldn't loose previous valid input when entering a lot of information) <-

Below the JSF page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="revisionForm">
        <h1>JSF Validation Test</h1>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Code: " />
            <h:inputText id="inputCode" required="true"
                value="#{revisionBean.revision.id}"
                requiredMessage="Id is required" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Name: " />
            <h:inputText id="inputname"
                value="#{revisionBean.revision.name}"
                requiredMessage="Name is required" required="true" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:commandButton id="btnSubmit" value="Insert"
            action="#{revisionBean.submit}" />

        <h:messages></h:messages>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Could someone point me how could I ensure the validation without losing valid values for other fields?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not the default behavior. However, cause of problem is not visible information provided so far.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC I was mixing the wrong references in my pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong references in the maven file (pom.xml)

```
<!-- jsf-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- jsf-impl  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

After changing to the right references the problem was gone:

```
<!-- jsf-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.16</version>
</dependency>

<!-- jsf-impl  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```